# Using Derivatives and Tangent Line to Find Area

Tags: functions, derivatives, inverse, area

Let $(a, b)$ be an arbitrary point on the graph of $y=\frac1x$ ($x>0$). Prove that the area of the triangle formed by the tangent line through $(a,b)$ and the coordinate axes is $2$ square units.

I know that I need to use derivatives and I've already come up with $f'(a)=\frac{1}{2a^2}$, but I am not sure how to use that or where to go from there.

Thanks!

Comment: Your derivative calculation isn't quite right. The slope of the tangent line through the point $(a,b)$ should be $\frac{-1}{a^2}$, not $\frac{1}{2a^2}$.

Comment: Find the equation of the tangent line. Then find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts of this line.

Comment: You should draw a graph. The formula for the area of a triangle is pretty simple, so the problem is simply to find the intersection of your tangent line (whose equation you need to full write as in $y(x) = b + f'(a) (x-a)$) with each axis.

Answer (score 2):

First, we compute the derivative of the function $ f(x) = \frac{1}{x} $, which is actually $ -\frac{1}{x^2} $. (If you want to know more about this, try looking up "Quotient Rule" in Google!)

So the tangent line at $ (a,b) = (a, \frac{1}{a}) $ should satisfy the following:

- Its slope must be $ - \frac{1}{a^2} $ at all values of x.
- It must pass through $ (a, \frac{1}{a}) $.

With those conditions in mind, we can set up the equation of the line: $ y=-\frac{1}{a^2}(x-a)+\frac{1}{a} $. Now compute the x-intercept and y-intercept. Those are $ 2a \text{ and } \frac{2}{a} $, respectively. Therefore the area of the triangle equals to $ 2a \times \frac{2}{a} \times \frac{1}{2} $, which is 2 units.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

we have $f'(x)=-1/x^2$ thus we get the slope of our tangent as $m=-1/a^2$ and the tangent line is given by
$y=-1/a^2x+n$ For the point at the curve we have $x=a,y=1/a$ and our tangentline is given by $y=-1/a^2x+2/a$. therefore the area is $\frac{2}{a}2a\frac{1}{2}=2$